# can next js api endpoint be access from other app

Tags: next.js

I am developing a web app using react on Next js framework.I have created API route that components of the web app gets data from. Now I want to create a mobile app using can i use the same API endpoint to get data in the mobile app also.

I am using next js 13 latest app directory

Comment: Yes, you can definitely use the same API endpoint that you have created for your web app in your mobile app as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all is same like you use express server.
But if you want to use it for sensitive actions like authorized users, please use security options like API key or JWT token.

Comment: Thanks, it will help me.  can you suggest where i can learn API key and JWT

Comment: OfCourse. You can use these links to create a secure JWT
Learn basic nextjs API: 
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

A useful lib for sign and decode JWT:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

A ready lib for use session with JWT method:
https://next-auth.js.org/